# __declspec(dllexport) forces wrong template override compile error

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, c++14

While creating a subclass of a template class I noticed I got an error on an overloaded function.
This compiler error was correct since one of the overloads was using a copy and the type was not copyable.
However, I was not using that function (correct overload or not). So I was surprised to get this error

After searching around a bit and reproducing in godbolt the culprit seemed to be __declspec(dllexport).
[Reproduction in godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/4j83x8Eov)

Removing the declspec seems to result in the correct compilation.
Code in godbolt:

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template<class V>
struct Foo{


    void update(const V& v);
    void update(V&& v);

    std::vector<V> values;
};

template<class V>
void Foo<V>::update(const V& v)
{
    values[0] = v;
}

template<class V>
void Foo<V>::update(V&& v)
{
    values[0] = std::move(v);
}

struct __declspec(dllexport) Bar : public Foo<std::unique_ptr<int>>
{

};

int main() 
{    
    Bar f;
    
    auto i = std::make_unique<int>(5);
    //f.update(i);
    //f.update(std::move(i));
}
```

My questions are mostly, how is declspec causing this behavior?
And, is there anything that can be done about this in the template class or derived class?

Error log:

> (19): error C2280:
> 'std::unique_ptr>
> &std::unique_ptr>::operator =(const
> std::unique_ptr> &)': attempting to
> reference a deleted function          with            [
>               _Ty=int             ]   C:/data/msvc/14.16.27023.1/include\memory(2338): note: see declaration of
> 'std::unique_ptr>::operator ='           with
>           [
>               _Ty=int             ]   C:/data/msvc/14.16.27023.1/include\memory(2338): note: 'std::unique_ptr>
> &std::unique_ptr>::operator =(const
> std::unique_ptr> &)': function was
> explicitly deleted            with            [
>               _Ty=int             ]   (18): note: while compiling class template member function 'void
> Foo>>::update(const V &)'
>           with            [
>               _Ty=int,
>               V=std::unique_ptr>             ]   (29): note: see reference to class template instantiation
> 'Foo>>' being compiled
>           with            [
>               _Ty=int             ]

Comment: exporting templates makes no sense at all. instantiations can occur inside the dll and/or inside the dll user and will probably/likely lead to Undefined Behaviour. Just don't do it.

Comment: When you export a class from a DLL, the compiler has no choice but to instantiate and export all member functions of that class. It can't know what functions will be called by the modules linking to that DLL. Yes, normally a member function of a template is not instantiated until it's called - but the DLL has to be fully compiled and linked before the client code using it is even written. There's no time machine to go back and instantiate those functions retroactively, so they all have to be instantiated prospectively.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation @IgorTandetnik.
Would there be any way to change the template code so it wouldn't create an error?
I'm thinking something like SFINAE but I fear that is only for override solving not instantiation.

Comment: Even if you remove the offending `update` functions entirely, you'd still [have an error](https://godbolt.org/z/Pvf4TKPz5). That's because the compiler still needs to instantiate `std::vector` data member and all its member functions, and those include copy constructor and copy assignment operator.  Naturally, you can't change the implementation of `std::vector`. In fact, you don't even need a base class: `struct __declspec(dllexport) Bar { std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> v; };` already fails.